# Сompleteness of metric space(integral)

Tags: functional-analysis, education

Let C [0, 1] be the set of all continuous functions on the interval [0, 1]. Investigate the metric space $$d_1(f, g) = \int_0^1 |f (t) -g (t)|dt$$ I would be grateful for an explanation of how to do it.

Comment: First, check that the metric is in fact a metric. Then take a cauchy sequence and prove that limit exists.

Comment: @DogeChan In theory, I understand this, but as in practice, such an example with an integral can not do

Comment: Consider the $\lim \sup (x_n)$ and $\lim \inf (x_n)$. If you can show that $\lim \sup (x_n) \leq \lim \inf (x_n)$ in this metric for a cauchy sequence $(x_n(t))$, then you can prove a limit exists.

Comment: @DogeChan Well, it's a little unclear, but thank you, I'll go further to understand

Comment: Look for an example of a Cauchy sequence of continuous functions in this metric that has no (continuous) limit. It exists. this site has examples.